# Issue reading specific node using XML2JS javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to pull together some javascript to read information from my airconditioner on my network. I am not a developer so may be missing something as the code I am using is pulled form some examples found here and elsewhere. When i use it with some example servers I can get it to work just not with my XML.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<iZS10.3>
<request>getSystemData</request>
<mac>001ec0a14c2e</mac>
<authenticated>1</authenticated>
<system>
<type>12</type>
<name>MYAIR3</name>
<MyAppRev>7.4</MyAppRev>
<zoneStationHasUnitControl>4</zoneStationHasUnitControl>
<dhcp>1</dhcp>
<ip>192.168.1.200</ip>
<netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
<gateway>192.168.1.1</gateway>
<unitcontrol>
<airconOnOff>1</airconOnOff>
<fanSpeed>3</fanSpeed>
<mode>2</mode>    
<unitControlTempsSetting>0</unitControlTempsSetting
<centralActualTemp>20.3</centralActualTemp>
<centralDesiredTemp>24.0</centralDesiredTemp>
<airConErrorCode>    </airConErrorCode>
<activationCodeStatus>0</activationCodeStatus
><numberOfZones>8</numberOfZones>
<maxUserTemp>32.0</maxUserTemp>
<minUserTemp>16.0</minUserTemp>
<availableSchedules>8</availableSchedules>
</unitcontrol>
<zs103TechSettings>
<numberofConstantZones>1</numberofConstantZones>
<zsConstantZone1>1</zsConstantZone1>
<zsConstantZone2>0</zsConstantZone2>
<zsConstantZone3>0</zsConstantZone3>
<tempSensorSelect>0</tempSensorSelect>
<returnAirOffset>0.0</returnAirOffset>
<controlZoneNumber>0</controlZoneNumber>
<newAirFitted>0</newAirFitted>
<ACinfo>0</ACinfo>
<systemID>16</systemID>
</zs103TechSettings>
</system>
</iZS10.3>
```

My code:

```
var options = {
   hostname: '192.168.1.200',
   port: 80,
   path: '/getSystemData',
   method: 'GET'
};


var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (systemdata) {
parseString(systemdata,{trim:true,childkey:9,explicitArray:false,explicitChildren:false}, 
function (err, result) {
           var output= (result);
           console.dir (output);
           console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
          console.log("End");
       });
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
req.end();
```

You'll note my var output is only written here to  brings back result. If i do this it successfully brings back the first node of the XML output. If i try and ask it to bring back a specific element i.e

```
var output= (result.iZS10.3.system.unitcontrol.centralActualtemp);
```

Gives

```
    /Users/Documents/workspace/XML Stream/xml2js.js:43
          var output= (result.iZS10.3.system.unitcontrol.centralActualtemp);
                                   ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Is there a way i should be formatting this in my output line?

If i just ask for result with no nodes.

```
{ 'iZS10.3': 
   { request: 'getSystemData',
     mac: '001ec0a14c2e',
     authenticated: '1',
     system: 
      { type: '12',
        name: 'MYAIR3',
        MyAppRev: '7.4',
        zoneStationHasUnitControl: '4',
        dhcp: '1',
        ip: '192.168.1.200',
        netmask: '255.255.255.0',
        gateway: '192.168.1.1',
        unitcontrol: [Object],
        zs103TechSettings: [Object] } } }
```

My stringify brings back every level and attribute with no problems.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: Can you please also add a sample output you're getting? Also, it might be a good idea to check the type of output you're addressing.

Comment: Post edited to show full error as it's messy in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result.iZS10.3.system` implies the following structure:

```
result: {
    iZS10: {
        3: {
            system: ...
        }
    }
}
```

You're probably instead looking for `result["iZS10.3"].system`, which implies the following structure:

```
result: {
    iZS10.3: {
        system: ...
    }
}
```

The problem in your initial approach is that the dot is used to address nested properties, but your `.3` is a part of a property name, not a property by itself. You can work around it by using the array notation as shown above.

Comment: Thanks Nit. Works beautifully. I knew I had to do something like that but couldn't find the syntax.